# Starting a new web site, Search Engine Jumpstart yes or no

Tags: search-engine, startup

I'm starting a new webs site and they offer me for Search Engine Jumpstart, should I buy it?
What's your opinion about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search Engine Jumpstart says that you get rapid indexing on Google, Yahoo, and Bing (in days). There are easier ways to do this yourself: Ping your website using a service like Pingomatic.
In the end it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the features of the services, It it's SEO then it's use to market your site on google, bing etc... ranks it so more people can you find you based on what you provide, finding you through keywords, it's a good way to start if you actually have product